# GridBagLayout is not adding my panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, paintcomponent

I am trying to add a three panels using `GridBagLayout` in `JFrame`. When the default layout is set, the panel is added without any problem, but when layout is changed to `GridBagLayout` and panel is added in `JFrame`, then the output is an empty frame.

Here is the code for `MainFrame`:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    CirclePanel[] cp;

    MainFrame() throws IOException{
        cp = new CirclePanel[3];
        for(int i = 0 ;i <3 ; i ++)
            cp[i]= new CirclePanel(i+1);

        this.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());//when this line is not set then 
                                       //add(cp[0]) adds the panel
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx=1;
        gc.weighty=1;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=0;

        add(cp[1],gc);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried different step but was unable to add the panel using `GridBagLayout` or at least I was unable to show panel.

I want to add 3 consecutive panels with equal width by incrementing `gc.gridx`.
The `Main` class contains only the `main` method, which is calling the `MainFrame` constructor.

In my custom panel class (`CirclePanel`) I used the `paintComponent` method to draw circles.

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

    private int mainCirclex ;//= getWidth()/2;
    private int mainCircley ;//= getHeight()/2;
    private final int mainCircler =1200;
    private final double ampRadius = 0.1;
//  private MakeArrays ma;
    private int[] firstCir;

    public CirclePanel(int num) throws IOException{
        firstCir = new int[175];
/*      ma = new MakeArrays();
        if(num == 1)
            firstCir = ma.getFirstCir();
        else if(num == 2)
            firstCir = ma.getSecondCir();
        else if(num == 3)
            firstCir = ma.getThirdCir();
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

            //////////main circle////////////////////
            //amplifying radius and setting x & y
            mainCircley = getHeight()/2;
            mainCirclex = getWidth()/2;
            int radius =  (int) (mainCircler*ampRadius);
            //drawing
            g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g2d.drawOval(mainCirclex - radius, mainCircley - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
            /////////end main circle///////////

            //////////////sub circles//////////////
            int min = Math.min(mainCirclex, mainCircley);
            int r2 = Math.abs(min - radius) / 160;
            int j =0;
            for (int i = 0; i <360; i++) {

                if(j>=175) break;
                if(i%2==0){
                    double t = 2 * Math.PI * i / 360; 
                    int r = (int) (firstCir[j]*ampRadius);
                    //System.out.println(firstCir[j]);
                    int x = (int) Math.round(mainCirclex + r * Math.cos(t));
                    int y = (int) Math.round(mainCircley - r * Math.sin(t));
                    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                    g2d.fillOval(x - r2, y - r2, 2 * r2, 2 * r2);
                    j++;
                }  
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: When these kind of things happen to me, the first thing I do is add `setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));` or change the background color of the component to see if it is actually getting added.  Second, your `CirclePanel` should be overriding `getPreferredSize` and returning some indication of how big to would normally like to be.  You could also add `gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` to force the panel to occupy the entire available cell space

Comment: I summarized my question @MadProgrammer.

Comment: Sorry, but now it's worse.  The problem isn't with the `GridBagLayout`, the problem is with your `CirclePanel`, but you didn't include `MakeArrays` which made it impossible to 100% certain of the problem or how it might best be fixed

Comment: makearrays class is just getting values from file and converting these values in int array @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried gc.fill = GridBagConstraint,BOTH,it added the panel but when i tried to add another panel by doing increment in gc.gridx++, it showes the panel but the background of that panel changed to default and also points on that circle are not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added all 3 panels by incrementing the `gridx` value. To make it work I did the following:

1. Added the line `gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` to allow the panels to resize and fill extra space.
2. Called `setBackground` in the panels' constructor instead of `fillRect` in `paintComponent`. It saves you the trouble of calculating the size of the panel.
3. Overrode the `getPreferredSize` of the panels:

   ```
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

       int size = (int) (2 * mainCircler * ampRadius);
       return new Dimension(size, size);
   }
   ```

   (You might want to redo the calculation.)
4. Called `pack` on the frame instead of `setSize`.

[image]

**Explanation**

The panels you are adding to the frame are empty from the layout manager's point of view - they don't have any child components. This means that panels will retain their default preferred is, which is 10x10 (`System.out.println(cp[1].getPreferredSize())`) and they will be added to the frame with those dimensions.

Custom painting is not taken into account automatically when computing the preferred size of a component. If the preferred size is too small for the painting, it will not be displayed (or only part of it will). Overriding the `getPreferedSize` method of the panels to give the correct dimensions will tell the frame how to display them when `pack` is called.

**Edit: comment answer**

> When I call `setBackground` to color the panels in their constructor it works fine, but when I try to use `fillRect` in `paintComponent` then the 1st panel is colored, but the next 2 panels aren't. Why is that?

Because of a *very common* misunderstanding (which is why I recommended point 2).

The `getXXX()` (`X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`) do not state the following explicitly, but they are derived from `getBounds()`, which reads:

> Gets the bounds of this component in the form of a `Rectangle` object. The bounds specify this component's width, height, and location **relative to its parent**.

(emphasis mine.) So the bounds are in the **parent's coordinate system**. However, `Graphics.fillRect` paints with the given bounds in the **component's coordinate system** (the `Graphics` object passed to `paintComponent` is for painting the component, not its parent).

Then in order to paint the panel in its own coordinate system, we need

```
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

because a component always starts at `(0,0)` in its own coordinate system. Using

```
g2d.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

takes the position of the panel in the parent and passes it to *some non-special* position in the panel. Moreover, if the panel is located in the parent's `(300,300)`, but the panel is less than `(300,300)` in size, then the drawing **in the panel** would in theory start **outside of the panel**. So, you see no painting.

The first panel paints because its `(0,0)` coincides with its parent's `(0,0)`.

Comment: it works perfectly thanks for the explanation. I have one more simple question when i call `setBackground`  to color panels in panel's constructor it works fine but when i try to use `fillrect` in `paintComponent` and then add in `GridBagLayout` then 1st panel is colored but the next 2 panels wont get colored. why is that?

Comment: thanks for the explanation it is really helpful and gives clear understanding about the positions of components.